# Reload tableView section without reloading header section - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to reload tableView section instead of reloading the whole tableview because I have a textfield in the header section and when I call `self.tableView.reloadData()` my keyboard get closed.

I've tried the code below but I get this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 5 from section 2 which only contains 4 rows before the update'` So please where would be my issue?

```
    let newCount = self.placeArray.count

    var newIndexPaths = NSMutableArray(capacity: newCount)

    for var i = 0 ; i < newCount ; i++ {
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 2)
        newIndexPaths.addObject(indexPath)
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(newIndexPaths as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Such code easily causes inconsistencies, don't be afraid to call the datasource method to get the number of rows.

Comment: @A-Live I'm sorry I didn't understand how to make it?

Comment: Use `numberOfRowsInSection` instead of copying the logic from there, this way the number must always be correct. You haven't show or mention any modification of the number of rows so I assume you don't do that, otherwise you have to take care of changing the number accordingly depending on when you get the number and modify the datasource.

Comment: I think you are giving me the solution but I'm not getting you. I'm updating the `numberOfRows` with the new array. @A-Live

Comment: You are trying to update more rows than there is, table view assumes you are trying to remove a row - that is caused by your mistake at calculation of the number of rows.

Comment: Refer to [Reload section without reloading section header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20802648/6521116)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use `UITableView`'s `reloadSections` method instead.

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 2), with: .none)
```

Comment: How can I update the header and footer of a section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531768/uitableview-grouped-section-footer-not-updating-after-reload

Comment: For some reason I have to cast NSIndexSet to IndexSet in Swift 3: `self.myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: index) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)`

Comment: this will reload both the section and the section headerView. I'm surprised by the upvotes to this answer

Comment: This is not the correct answer, it is reloading the section header but it just has no animation

Comment: This is not the right answer. This reloads the whole section including header

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3.0.1:**

```
let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 0)

tableView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none) // or fade, right, left, top, bottom, none, middle, automatic
```

Comment: This is Reloading Header also.

Comment: If you animate this, you can see that it very clearly reloads the section header

Answer (score 15):

*Swift 3.1 Xcode 8.3.3 Answer :)*

The **problem** is - each section includes header of course, so section is:

### section = header + footer + rows

The **answer** is - reload rows directly by IndexPath.
Example:

1. Let's say you've got **1 section** in your table and 'array' of something you use as datasource for table:

   `let indexes = (0..<array.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }`
2. Now we've got array of indexes of cell we want to reload, so:

   `tableView.reloadRows(at: indexes, with: .fade)`

Answer (score 11):

**Note:**

- `UITableView.reloadData()` will reload all the table.   [Docs about reloaddata](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata#discussion)

  > reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including
  >   cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For
  >   efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are
  >   visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the
  >   reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method
  >   when it wants the table view to completely reload its data.
- `UITableView.reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` will reload specific section( **including section header and section footer**). [Docs about reloadsections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections)
- `UITableView.reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` will reload the specified rows. [Docs about reloadRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

So here `reloadSections` will not works here. **If your header section data and status not change, call this method will make no diffrence by sight.**

**Solution:** use `reloadRows` to load the rows of all the sections or of the specific section. **Note: here you can just load the visible rows, others will be loaded when you scroll you view.** You also can refer to [Get all indexPaths in a section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50367280/6521116) for more solutions

```
var indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

/* just roload visible rows of specified section
indexPaths = indexPaths.filter({ (indexPath) -> Bool in
    return indexPath.section == SECTION_INDEX_NEED_TO_RELOAD
})
*/
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths!, with: .none)
```

Comment: Hey, Good answer and good document. But when I call `reloadRows` my header will also reload, In my case my header is hidden. If you have any solution for this specific issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

You can just reload section as below:

```
tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .none)
```

or

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
```

Here **zero** represent the index it will reload.

Reload multiple sections:

```
tableView.reloadSections([0, 1, 3], with: .none)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Swift 5]**

You want to reload all rows in a section. So you can do:

```
let rowIndexes: [IndexPath] = Array(0...YOUR_ARRAY-1).map({ 
    return IndexPath(row: $0, section: YOUR_SECTION) 
})
```

To get all possible row indexes for this section. Then you just have to reload rows for these indexes:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: rowsIndexes, with: .fade)
```

**The section won't be reloaded.**

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but here is a solution for 2D array (in case if your tableView has sections and each section has some items). This will reload every cell in every section but won't touch header/footer of the section.

```
    let indexPaths = (0..<array.count).map { section in
        (0..<array[section].nestedArray.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }
    }.flatMap { $0 }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 5

> Here is put static index reload which is 1st index, you can change as per your requirement.

```
self.tblView.reloadSections(IndexSet(index: 1), with: .none)
```

Comment: why NSIndexSet? i we can use Indexset

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have just update my answer.