# UITableView jumps when expanding cell with autolayout.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I've been searching and can't find a solution to this problem. My current code is based on [Reload section without reloading section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802648/reload-section-without-reloading-section-header).

I'm trying to grow a uitableview cell when the user presses into the cell. I have a UITableViewCell subclass with a UILabel that is initially limited to two lines of text. When the the user presses the UILabel I set the numberOfLines property in the UILabel to 0 so it expands to as many lines as needed.

Here is my code from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (((NSNumber *)expandedCells[indexPath.section]).boolValue)
{
     labelExpandingCell.cellLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
} else
{
     labelExpandingCell.cellLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
}
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Sometimes this works fine, typically when the UITableView's contentOffset.y == 0. Usually the tableview jumps to the backwards 100 pixels or so when I execute this code. Here is an example log from before and after this code is ran.

2016-03-25 14:57:08.549 TableViewTest[485:129926] Content offset before update: 153.500000
2016-03-25 14:57:08.568 TableViewTest[485:129926] Content offset after update: 136.500000

Why would autolayout be causing my tableview to jump backwards when I expand the currently visible cell?

Comment: I'm getting something similar with code that used to work. Not sure when this started. iOS 9 sdk possibly? Sure don't wanna go back to setting cell heights manually!!

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue by implementing the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method in my tableview's delegate. I believe the issue was with the tableview not properly estimating the height of the previous sections in my tableview without this method implemented, thus jumping when I'd update a section in the tableview.

Comment: Yes I solved by adding fix height and removing estimatedHeight.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the UITableView

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT`

If yes, check ensure that your UILabel constraints are correctly applied to cell.
You can avoid implementing "estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath" method if you set the above two properties.

Comment: it's not work for me!